# Calculate within-group covariance matrix only of numeric columns from nested list

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the within-group covariance matrix from a nested list, where the sub-lists represent the groups, and I am having trouble ignoring the non-numeric columns in each sub-list.

Here is a dummy list for my example:

```
#Create dataframes ABC and DEF, where 'left' and 'right' columns are numeric and the 'up' column contains characters
ABC <- cbind.data.frame(left = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 4, 7), right = c(5, 8, 4, 6, 9, 6, 4, 3), up = c("aa","aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "cc"))
ABC$up <- as.character(ABC$up)
DEF <-  cbind.data.frame(left = c(7, 2, 9, 3, 1, 7, 8, 4), right = c(3, 6, 1, 4, 9, 7, 2, 1) , up = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc"))
DEF$up <- as.character(DEF$up)

#Create a list called mylist, containing two dataframes: ABC and DEF
mylist <- list(ABC = ABC, DEF = DEF)
mylist
$ABC
  left right up
1    2     5 aa
2    3     8 aa
3    5     4 bb
4    6     6 bb
5    2     9 bb
6    8     6 cc
7    4     4 cc
8    7     3 cc

$DEF
  left right up
1    7     3 aa
2    2     6 aa
3    9     1 aa
4    3     4 aa
5    1     9 bb
6    7     7 bb
7    8     2 bb
8    4     1 cc
```

As you can see from mylist, I have a character column I would like to ignore when calculating the within-group covariance matrix. I would like my resulting within-group covariance list to look like this:

```
perfect.mylist.cov
$ABC
           left     right
left   5.125000 -2.160714
right -2.160714  4.267857

$DEF
           left     right
left   8.982143 -5.303571
right -5.303571  8.696429
```

I have tried two things, and they both return a similar error:

```
within.group.cov.1 <- rapply(mylist, classes = "numeric", f = cov, how = "list")

Error in (function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson",  : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'


within.group.cov.2 <- lapply(X=mylist, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) cov(y) else y))})

Error in cov(y) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

I am not sure whether I am failing, because I am incorrectly working with a list structure, or whether I am not using the cov function correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to subset the columns and apply the `cov` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) cov(x[(c('left', 'right'))]))
```

-output

```
#$ABC
#           left     right
#left   5.125000 -2.160714
#right -2.160714  4.267857

#$DEF
#           left     right
#left   8.982143 -5.303571
#right -5.303571  8.696429
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much. Any idea why I received the initial errors?